# How to implement the prev and next button

Tags: android

I want to implement 2 activities , one is a listview with image and text which works well now. The other one is a onClicklistener when I click any ListItem it will start another activity to show more information, with 1 previous button and next button to see the Prev information or next. However there is something wrong with the button. It can only see the previous one and next one once. Which means you can't click the next button twice. Any suggestions will be appreciated  .

Here is my main activity code

```
package com.example.manchesterunited;


import com.example.manchesterunited.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {


static PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

setListAdapter(adapter);

 }



public void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int pos, long id){
    int playerId = (int)id;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected       "+data.getName(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("playerId", playerId);
    startActivity(intent);

}
 }
```

And here is the second activity

```
package com.example.manchesterunited;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoActivity extends Activity  {

TextView dobText;
TextView pobText;   
TextView internationalText;
Button prevButton;
Button nextButton;
PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    dobText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    pobText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    internationalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    prevButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev);
    nextButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int playerId = intent.getExtras().getInt("playerId");  
     dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getDob()));
        pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getPob()));
        internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(playerId).getInternational());


        prevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int newId = playerId-1;
                         dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getDob()));
                            pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getPob()));
                            internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(newId).getInternational());

                    }

                });

                nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int newId = playerId+1;
                         dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getDob()));
                            pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getPob()));
                            internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(newId).getInternational());

                    }

                });}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_info, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: You are not saving the state of the variable newId on playerId. Use playerId++ for nextButton and playerId-- for prevButton and remove the newId variable. And declare playerId as an attribute of the Activity not as final.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the playerID.

You're just getting a new ID.

you should put

```
int newId = playerId+1;
playerID = newId; //insert this line
```

so that when you click again,

playerID gets updated.

Comment: you can not do playerId = newId; because playerId is declared as final.

Comment: he can easily declare another global variable

Answer (score 0):

You are always adding just 1 to player ID which will now point to next item. But as soon as you re-click the button it will have the same player ID that was passed through intent. So again it will add in the same value. Make a new variable which will store the current player ID that is visible and keep on incrementing it then you will be able to browse next and vice versa in the previous case.

You can't increment player ID as it has been declared as final, so you can either make a global variable or put a variable in intent and increment it on button clicks.

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
{
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //make newId global then it will work. And keep on updating it when the button is clicked accordingly.

                         newId = playerId+1;

                         dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getDob()));
                            pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(newId).getPob()));
                            internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(newId).getInternational());

                    }

                });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on InfoActivity,

```
private int playerId;
...
...onCreate(...){
    ...
    playerId = intent.getExtras().getInt("playerId");
    prevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             ...
             playerId--;
             dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getDob()));
             pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getPob()));
             internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(playerId).getInternational());
          }
    }
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             ...
             playerId++;
             dobText.setText("Birthdate:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getDob()));
             pobText.setText("Birthplace:"+String.valueOf(data.getPlayer(playerId).getPob()));
             internationalText.setText("International:"+data.getPlayer(playerId).getInternational());
          }
    }
}
```